# SQL IN() multi-column condition with static right operand

Tags: sql, sqlite

I definitely know there is a right syntax for this but can't remember of find what it is: I need to do something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "table"
WHERE
    ("dep_date","ret_date") IN (('2019-10-10','2019-10-15'),('2019-10-11','2019-10-16'))
```

Except this syntax doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for defining a static multi-column lookup for the right operand of IN()?

Comment: That syntax does work in PostgreSQL. Btw, what's your database?

Comment: That is valid SQL-99 syntax.

Comment: I checked with SQLite so far... it says `"SQL error or missing database (row value misused)"`. They usually follow PG's take on SQL, so I didn't check others yet. Adding tag as it may be specific.

Comment: Maybe try dropping double quotes ?

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Should work perfectly.

Comment: Well... "tuples" are perfectly legal according to the SQL standard. However, few engines support them fully. PostgreSQL is a good example. Oracle, DB2, and MariaDB offer support on some operators. SQL Server doesn't like them at all.

Comment: @TheImpaler MySQL supports them too...apparently not SQLite.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support all Postgresql functionality. If your target is sqlite, use sqlite when programming.

Comment: Ok, let's try a hack: what's the syntax for defining a static table so I can try `IN ( SELECT FROM )`

Comment: Hack found: it does seem to digest `IN ( VALUES ('2019-10-13','2019-10-22'),('2019-10-13','2019-10-22'))`; do you think it's also portable?

Comment: While the `VALUES` syntax works, it seems to evade any index optimisation; it literally treats the condition as a boolean function on every row. So it's no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below way -

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "table"
WHERE ((dep_date='2019-10-10' and ret_date='2019-10-15') or 
      (dep_date='2019-10-11' and ret_date='2019-10-16'))
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to the OP.

Comment: Well, with the `sqlite` tag added, it does answer the question. Although I found SQLite does digest `IN ( VALUES ('2019-10-13','2019-10-22'),('2019-10-13','2019-10-22'))`, this seems to evade any index optimisation; it literally treats the condition as a boolean function on every row. So it's no good. So indeed the best next option seems to be to expand the set to and/or conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery with UNION ALL after the IN clause:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "table"
WHERE  ("dep_date","ret_date") IN (
  select '2019-10-10', '2019-10-15' 
  union all
  select '2019-10-11','2019-10-16'
)
```

You can find more about **Row Values** in SQLite here: https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html

Comment: While this syntax is valid, it does seem to hit the same hitch as `IN (VALUES (),()...)`: it's not solved by the optimizer, it literally treats it as a boolean condition on every row so no index optimisation.